# Ubuntu 20.04 freeze on spectre X 360

Tags: nvidia, graphics, freeze

so I have an HP Spectre 15x, dual-booting Ubuntu 20.04/Windows 10.
Specs are:
I7 8750H (Coffe Lake)
GTX Nvidia 1050 Ti Mobile
Touchable screen 3840x2160

I am dealing with freezing issues.
When I did install Linux from a USB stick, 
it did freeze in the installation process, 
so I did the run installation in safe mode (taught changing drivers will help).

After Linux is installed, 
So when I boot up ubuntu, it sometimes(70%) freezes after login, and also it sometimes freezes while I am using it. Sometimes I even can't get to log in before it stacks.
Then I need to do a hard reset.
Also sound sometimes is not working.

I did try to change Nvidia drivers. 
First I did use 440 drivers. Problem with Nvidia 440 driver second monitor not detected. 
I did try change to x opensource driver it shows black screen after boot. 
At the moment I am using Nvidia 435 driver it is working, but freezes a lot.

I did try to add nomodeset in grub file - GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset".
Then built-in desktop freezes before login with hp logo, 
bet when I add a second display, Linux work on a second display.

Also, in Nvidia settings when I set to performance mode, if I put a power saver, it uses integrated graphics(Intel HD 630), and the second monitor is not detected then.

I did have ubuntu 19.04 and did work ok on this laptop, but I would like to use 20.04. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer so much as a confirmation.  Desktop HP Pavillion 690 0073w, intel i5-9600, 16gb ram, Nvidia 1660ti.  This system was my 2nd UBUNTU fresh install.  The first one had an old nvidia gtx 240s graphics.  It installed and worked fine.  The one with 1660ti boots to gnome and STOPS.  I cannot unfreeze it.  It proceeds no further.  I thought it was the install process, so I re-installed 4 times.  On the fourth time, I took a stab at replacing the relatively current NVIDIA card with an old AMD radeon hd 6450 card.  I did a hard restart.  Everything booted fine.  I was able to get past the livepatch set up screen and complete the install.  That showed me that the graphics card is the problem.